# How do I modify the abstract in Arxiv (without changing the paper)

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv, hyperlinks

I recently changed the location of a link to be in the abstract part. While it works perfectly in the paper, the link doesn't work of Arxiv (the main page) because it's in the end of a sentence and they added the "." to the link instead of realizing that it's the end of the sentence.
Do I need to resubmit even though i'm not changing the actual paper? How terrible is increasing the version of a  paper (I'll probably have to change it again in a month or two)?

Comment: I guess up to 5 times revisions are allowed for a one submission. If the submission is online, you cannot make any changes rather than v2.

Comment: It's going to be v3. How bad is it? does anybody cares (it's under review)?

Comment: All the versions will be available online, however your arxiv link to title refers to the latest version. I guess it’s alright.

Answer (score 4):

The only changes that do not generate a new version number are adding a journal reference or DOI. Changing the abstract *will* generate a new version. As far as I am aware there are no limitations to the number of updates, but at some point arXiv will stop including udpates in the daily mailings (I believe after version 5). Making many new versions with minor changes might give the impression though that you have not carefully checked your manuscript before submitting, so generally I would recommend to save such small updates for after the paper is accepted or revised. This would also be less work for yourself and for the arXiv moderators.

Personally, in the case you mention, I would not bother to update it now. Most people are smart enough to try to remove the period at the end of the URL.